# my React component renders a 404 error when trying to GET the api data? React, Axios, Api

Tags: reactjs, api, http-status-code-404, use-effect

When trying to render my api data to list all of the brands from the api, the console shows a 404 error 'GET https://v1-sneakers.p.rapidapi.com/v1/sneakers/brands 404 (Not Found)' it worked when I used this endpoint in a different component. but I decided to make it it's own page. I am using a 'useEffect' to render the api data. I'm not sure if it is how I have the routing set up or if it is how I am getting the data.

[image]

Brand.js

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import api from '../api';
// import axios from "axios";

const Brand = () => {

    const [brands, setBrands]= useState([]);

    

  useEffect(() => {
      const fetchData = () => {
          api.getBrand().then((response)=>{
              setBrands(response.data.results);
              console.log(response.data.results);
          });
      };

      fetchData();
  }, [])

    
    return (
        <div className="brand-container">
        {/* {brands && (
            <ul className="brand_list">
                {brands.map((brand)=>{
                    return(
                    <li>{brand.shoe}</li>
                    )
                })}
            </ul>
        ) } */}
            
        </div>
    )
}


export default Brand;
```

Api.js

```
import axios from "axios";

const API_KEY = process.env.RAPID_API_KEY
export default {

getData: () =>
axios({
  method: 'GET',
  url: 'https://v1-sneakers.p.rapidapi.com/v1/sneakers',
  params: {limit: '24'},
  headers: {
    'x-rapidapi-key': 'f2326766a3msh573dd850eaeab1fp181777jsnf7f3daf5cc0a',
    'x-rapidapi-host': 'v1-sneakers.p.rapidapi.com'
  }

}),

getDataId: (id) => 
  axios({
    method: 'GET',
  url: 'https://v1-sneakers.p.rapidapi.com/v1/sneakers/' + id,
  headers: {
    'x-rapidapi-key': 'f2326766a3msh573dd850eaeab1fp181777jsnf7f3daf5cc0a',
    'x-rapidapi-host': 'v1-sneakers.p.rapidapi.com'
  }
  }),

  getBrand: () =>
    axios({
      method: 'GET',
      url: 'https://v1-sneakers.p.rapidapi.com/v1/brands',
      headers: {
        'x-rapidapi-key': 'f2326766a3msh573dd850eaeab1fp181777jsnf7f3daf5cc0a',
        'x-rapidapi-host': 'v1-sneakers.p.rapidapi.com'
      }
    })
  


}

// f2326766a3msh573dd850eaeab1fp181777jsnf7f3daf5cc0a'
```

App.js

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch, useParams} from 'react-router-dom';

import Home from './components/Home'; 
import SearchBar from './components/SearchBar';
import Navbar from './components/Navbar';
import SneakerId from './components/SneakerId';
import About from './components/About'
import Brand from './components/Brand'


 const App = () => {


    return (
        <Router>
                    <Navbar />
            <Switch>
                <Route exact path="/about" component={About} />
                <Route exact path="/">
                   
                    <Home />
                </Route>
                <Route exact path="/:id">
                <SneakerId  />
                </Route>
                <Route exact path="/brands" component={Brand}/>
               
               
                
                
            </Switch>
        </Router>
    )
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

I have checked this API on RapidAPI Hub, and there is no endpoint with the `https://v1-sneakers.p.rapidapi.com/v1/sneakers/brands` URL. Instead, you should use the `https://v1-sneakers.p.rapidapi.com/v1/brands` endpoint, I believe.

Answer (score 0):

What you could do to make sure it's the API or your code is use a tool like [Postman](https://www.postman.com/product/tools/). If you enter all the credentials and get a correct response there but not in your application at least you know the data is coming from the API.

Did you try logging the id in the getDataId function to see if the value comes through?